# Coq prove a false list assumption

Tags: coq

Given the next theorem.

```
Theorem rev_injective_helper : forall (l : natlist) (n : nat),
    [] = l ++ [n] -> False.
Proof.
  intros l n H.
  unfold app in H.
  induction l. all: inversion H.
Qed.
```

**How to prove the next goal?**

```
1 subgoal
n : nat
l2 : natlist
H : [ ] = rev l2 ++ [n]
IHl2 : [ ] = rev l2 -> [ ] = l2
______________________________________(1/1)
[ ] = n :: l2
```

As I understand an assumption in this case is wrong  `H : [ ] = rev l2 ++ [n]` **how to finis the proof?** Thanks in advance!

**Update.**
Missing definitions:

```
Fixpoint app (l1 l2 : natlist) : natlist :=
  match l1 with
  | nil ⇒ l2
  | h :: t ⇒ h :: (app t l2)
  end.

Notation "x ++ y" := (app x y)
                     (right associativity, at level 60).

Fixpoint rev (l:natlist) : natlist :=
  match l with
  | nil ⇒ nil
  | h :: t ⇒ rev t ++ [h]
  end.
```

I'm trying to prove this theorem:

```
Theorem rev_injective : forall (l1 l2 : natlist),
    rev l1 = rev l2 -> l1 = l2.
```

Comment: Can you provide enough information to compile your definitions?

Comment: @pochinha the question updated, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say you have a false hypothesis in your context, so it doesn't matter what your are trying to prove, it will follow from falsehood.
To exploit this you can use the `exfalso` tactic which replaces your current goal by `False`. Then you should be able to conclude from `rev_injective_helper` and `H` no?